# How to add super admin to all sites

Tags: multisite, admin, network-admin

Is there a way to add super admins to ALL sites without having to add them to each site individually? My group of super admins needs access to all sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Super admins do have access to all sites, but they don't show up in "My Sites" by default, which I imagine is where you're looking. They'll want to go to the network admin (/wp-admin/network/, then go to all sites from there, then find the site they want to edit and click "Dashboard" (which appears on hover).

I like to think of "My Sites" almost as favorites, and only add myself to a site when I'll be accessing it frequently, as it reduces the list I have to pick through.

Does that make sense and clear up your question?

Answer (score 3):

Or For adding your sites on "My Sites" if you've missed them, then you can add them by go to
Network Admin > Dashboard > All Sites > Edit Your Desired Site > Users (Tab) > Add Existing User > Add your desired existing username and role it as "Admin"

Regards.

Comment: I hate when important UI is below the fold.

Answer (score 0):

I manage multisites with 50+ subsites.

I have multiple super admins and editors.

I installed and activated this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-user-sync/

Went to a user at the network level,
clicked the Sync All box,
all subsites instantly became automatically checked in a list.

When I saved the user and
went back to Users the
user had access to all subsites.

I love it when something (esp. plugins) do what they say they will do OOTB.

Chris